# jQuery: How to use a jQuery-plugin in receive-function of jquery-sortable

Tags: jquery

I am using Jeremy Huets notify-plugin (https://github.com/jhuet/jquery-notify) to display errors.

If I am using the plugin in the error function of a ajax-request I get `$.notify is not a function`.

If I am using the plugin outside the ajax-function it works.

```
$.notify('error occured', 'error');        //works

$.get("http://my.url",
    function () {
        //do something
 }).error(function () {
    //handle error
    $.notify('error occured', 'error');    //fails
});
```

The other jQuery-functions work inside the error function. How can i get the plugin to work inside the error-function?

I guess that all plugins do not work inside the error-function.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I found out that not the error-function is causing the problem. It is the jquery-sortable. The code is actually like this:

```
$.notify('error occured', 'error');        //works

$(".container").sortable({
    receive:function (event, ui) {
        //handle error
        $.notify('error occured', 'error');    //fails
    });
});
```

Comment: Urr, this shouldn't be the case. Are you sure you're not re-declaring `$` inside the `error()` function accidentally? What does `alert(typeof jQuery)` and `alert(typeof $)` give you when executed in the `error` handler?

Comment: It returns `function` as expected. I can access all the default jQuery-functions inside the error function using the same synthax. If do this `notify = $.notify;` ouside the function I can call it inside by using `notify()`. This workaround seems to work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that jQuery was accidentally included twice once before including jq-notify and once after.
This caused the `$` to be overridden by the second include. Therefore `$.notify` became `undefined`. Assigning it to a separate variable solved the problem temporarily but the correct solution is of course including jQuery only once.

Answer (score 0):

Notify is a totally separate library from Waypoints (!!), I just realized this myself.  You need to have notify included, along w JQuery:

http://notifyjs.com/